# Select v-model Object select

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How we select item props together in v-model
I mean i select something only take one value.
I want to select value it should be binding name and dept together
Because i will push the these values on table.

```
<select v-model="name">
  <option v-for="member in members" :key="member.id" :label="member.name" :value="member.name">
  </option>
</select>

data(){
  return {
    members: [{id: 1, name: 'alpkaan', dept: 'quality'}]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your select you must have a variable that will contain the selected value,
an event that will listen to each value change and with a method related to this event, you will be able to browse your object array to find the object with the selected value.

NOTE : I delete the id with `delete this.memberSelectedData.id` but you can leave it if you need it, here is a screenshot.

And there is the code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <select v-model="memberSelected" @change="slectMember()">
      <option v-for="member in members" :key="member.id" :label="member.name" :value="member.name"></option>
    </select>
    <p>Member name : {{memberSelected}}</p>
    <p>Member data : {{memberSelectedData}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "app",
  data() {
    return {
      members: [{ id: 1, name: "alpkaan", dept: "quality" }, { id: 2, name: "alpkaan2", dept: "quality2" }],
      memberSelected: "",
      memberSelectedData: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    slectMember() {
      this.members.map( member => {
        if(member.name === this.memberSelected){
          this.memberSelectedData = member
          delete this.memberSelectedData.id
        }
      })
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Seems like a good answer but please paste your code and don't put screenshots in here.
This will make it easier to find stuff for everyone else, which is the goal of StackOverflow.

Comment: And also, others can edit it - which in your case would make sense to use a computed instead of a method. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found one way it's running
:value="{'id':member.id, 'name':member.name}"

But;
Select button not work correctly. Because of v-model="name"

How solved this situation idk. :(

Comment: Please, try with the solution that I posted just above, I think it can help you

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

const members = ref([  
  {id:1, name:"James"},
  {id:2, name:"Jhon"},   
]);

const selectedMember = ref(undefined);

</script>

<template>
  <select v-model="selectedMember">
    <option :value="undefined">Select a Member</option>
    <template v-for="member in members" :key="member.id">
      <option :value="member">{{ member.name }}</option>
    </template>
  </select>
</template>
```